# How <p:dialog>'s position remain center of a page after increasing its size dynamically?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, modal-dialog

In my application I have a `<p:dialog>`, in the dialog I placed a `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` . If this is checked then one row below this will apear otherwise 
this row will hidden.By default dialog's position is center of the page. Now Problem is when I checked this `booleanCheckbox` the height and width of dialog is 
increased as new row's content is greater than previous `dialog` , then the position doesn't remain center of the page, I mean the dialog's size increases bottom and right side.
How I can display dialog at center after increasing its content? Any pointer will be very helpful to me .   Thanks,

Sory for my bad English.

code of .xhtml is given below:

```
<p:dialog id="popUp" widgetVar="popUpWidget"
  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false" modal="true">
    <p:row>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{adbBundle['addRemoveActivityManagers']}" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{activityListController.editActivityManager}" immediate="true">
            <p:ajax event="click" update="adminPanel" listener="#{activityListController.updateActivityManager}"/>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:row>
    <p:row rendered="#{activityListController.editActivityManager}">
        <p:column>
            <p:dataTable id="sourceManagerDataTable" value="#{activityListController.activitySourceUsers}" var="manager" liveScroll="true" scrollRows="5" 
                scrollHeight="125" selection="#{activityListController.selectedActivitySourceUsers}" selectionMode="multiple"
                filteredValue="#{activityListController.filteredSourceUsers}" scrollable="true" styleClass="activityManager">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Available Managers" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Full Name" sortBy="#{manager.lastName}" filterBy="#{manager.fullName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{manager.lastName}, #{manager.firstName}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>
    </p:row></p:dialog>
```

Comment: have you tried defining the style of the dialog itself?
something like: <p:dialog id="popUp" widgetVar="popUpWidget"
  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false" modal="true" style="text-align:center;">

Comment: I am not use any css to center it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when you click to the checkbox or check it call a function which re-renders your dialog so add this `onstart="setSize();"` to you `p:ajax`:

And below is the JavaScript function:

```
function setSize () {
 $(".ui-dialog").css ({
    "width": 300,
    "height": 200,
    "left": "50%",
    "top": "50%",
    "margin-left": -150,
    "margin-top": -100
  });
}
```

Don't forget if you decide to change `height` or `width` values you should give the margin values as -1/2 times of them. The values that I gave are not certain you should chande them if it should be bigger or whatever.

If you want to detect unchecked checkbox and set height due to it's state our function can be sth. like that:

```
function setSize () {
var checkBox = $(document.getElementById('myCheckBox'));
$('.ui-dialog').css ({
    'width' : 300,
    'height': 200,
    'left': "50%",
    'top': "50%",
    'margin-left': -150,
    'margin-top': -100
    });
if(!checkBox.checked) {//If it doesn't checked; it can be checkBox.attr('checked')
    $(".ui-dialog").css ({
        "height": 150, //New height value which is starting dialog height when it's unchecked
        "margin-top": -75
        });
    }
}
}
```

You should give the correct clientID of your checkbox which you can see in your browser's developer options also maybe instead of this; `height:auto;` can work as well.

Comment: Faruk Almali: this css sets dialog's fixed size at the time of dialog generation. So when check box remain unchek then position for new upcoming row 
remain blank and dialog is bigger than its content, and when checkbox is checked then the new row is displaying on that blank position. But I want to increase 
dynamically dialog's size when ckeckbox is checked also keep dialog's position center.Am I clear?

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer via my cellphone if sth. Wrong i will edit it 1 hour later.

Comment: thanks @Faruk Almali for reply, when checkbox is clicked then it is being large, all right. But when again unchecked this box then the dialog is not collapsed the blank space. can it be done like previous(when dialog is appears first time)?